# How to turn on progress bar in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have status bar but no progress bar there during loading pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft removed the progress bar when they rebuild IE9

> The IE9 team built the UI from the ground up, starting with nothing and only adding what was needed (rather than starting with IE8 and removing features).  Because the progress bar is very prone to error, sometimes remaining at less than 100% indefinitely regardless of whether the site was done loading.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the empty space between address/tab and home; then select "status bar" to restore it at the bottom of the window (also - restore menu by selecting "menu bar").

Comment: Why this answer is down voted ? Some idiots simply loves down voting !!!

Comment: I agree and upvoted, because the accepted answer is at least incomplete. You can have the status bar as answered by Toeknee. It just looks different as before.

Answer (score -2):

The status bar is at the bottom of the browser and typically does two things.

1. Shows information about the URL when you hover over a link.
2. Allows the user to adjust the zoom on the page.

In order to enable progress bar, just click View > Toolbars > Status Bar

Comment: "click View > Toolbars > Status Bar" - obviously I have Status bar turned on, but no progress bar during loading pages as it was in IE8. I want to have progress bar: http://www.askmehelpdesk.com/attachments/a/17073d1235819247-internet-explorer-status-bar-shows-waiting-message-page-doesnt-load-crash_1.jpg - thing you can see on that picture in right red "circle"